# Increase size of TabBar?

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

I am trying to create a tabBar with a background image, but it appears that its not big enough. It appears that the image background or doesnt start from the beggining or the background is not big enough.

How can I increase the size of it?

[image]

I want to achieve this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
init() {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "tabBarBackground")
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                ZStack {
                    Color.green
                        .opacity(0.1)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    
                    VStack {
                        dashboardView
                        
                    }
                    .font(.title2)
                }
                
                .tabItem {
                    Image("home-selected-ic")
                }
                assetsView
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("assets-unselected-ic")
                    }
                chatView
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("chat-unselected-ic")
                    }
                dAppsView
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("apps-unselected-ic")
                    }
                assetsView
                    .tabItem {
                        Image("wiz-unselected-ic")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the built-in TabView does not currently support it. You have to build your customized tab bar.